# How to determine file creation timestamp in java for linux/unix file system

Tags: java, linux, file

I have tried using the below code to get the file creation time of a file in linux system. But instead of giving the creation time , it is giving last modified time.
Please help me to get the file creation time in java for linux file system.

```
File f=new File("/var/fileName.csv");
Path p = f.toPath();
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(p, BasicFileAttributes.class);

System.out.println("creationTime: " + attr.creationTime().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: which file system do you use exactly? Do you mean ext2/3/4?

Comment: Even if the filesystem being used actually tracks creation time (not all do), there's no easy way to get it, as you have to invoke the `statx` syscall manually since there's no glibc wrapper function for it. Not surprising if the jre you're using doesn't support that.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#creationTime()) show the following:

> FileTime creationTime()
>
> Returns the creation time. The creation time is the time that the file was created.
>
> If the file system implementation does not support a time stamp to indicate the time when the file was created then this method returns an implementation specific default value, typically the last-modified-time or a FileTime representing the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

So it would appear that this is an issue with the filesystem you are on, and the corresponding filesystem implementation.